# Cordova modifying plist

Tags: cordova

I currently have the following for my plugin.xml

```
<platform name="ios">

    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="/*">
        <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <true/>
        <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
        <true/>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

I'm trying to modify the ios app's plist so that it has the following:

- `UIStatusBarHidden` set to YES
- `UIStatusBarHidden` set to YES
- `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` set to NO

The above code doesn't seem to work. Any ideas as to what I should be doing?